# How do you remove individual packages from the list in synaptic package manager?

Tags: apt, synaptic

I would like to be able to remove references to a particular, individual package in a repository.

If I do not want install something it would be nice to speed up apt-get update(by skipping those) and have a cleaner synaptic screen.

[image: synaptic]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, I don't believe that you can remove entries, or prevent them from showing up in Synaptic Package Manager without removing or disabling your repositories.

However, you can create custom filters based on a variety of criteria:

1. Start the Synaptic package manager
2. From the menu, Select Settings, then the Filter sub-menu. From here, you can create a  customized filter to include (or exclude) specific package from appearing in Synaptic.
3. Create a new filter (and name it accordingly).

   [image]
4. Define your filter(s) based on three criteria:

   - Status of package

     - Not-installed would be the only box checked in your case.
   - Section

     - This tab allows for applying greater granularity to the filter. Say, if you didn't want to see any un-installed packages only from the `Graphics` category, for example.
   - Properties

     - Pattern matching can be specified to include/exclude a specific character sequence.
5. Return to the main Synaptic window and click the `Custom Filters` button and then select your newly named filter.